# (Emacs) How to only show last directory in emacs shell?

Tags: emacs, directory, eshell

I would like to know if it is possible to show only last directory in eShell (Emacs Shell). For example, It's currently in path `/home/user/Programming/C++`. With current setup of eshell, `~/Programming/C++ $`, but I would like to show only this: `C++ $`.

Thanks

Comment: Look here for information https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellPrompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible - the prompt is generated by function stored in the `eshell-prompt-function` variable.  You can redefine it to whatever you want.  You can define it something like: `(lambda () (concat (car (last (split-string (eshell/pwd) "/"))) " $ "))`

See [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellPrompt) for examples.